# Fireox, how get tabs object?

Tags: firefox, tabs, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I try get tabs of current brouser window

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
```

and catch all new tabs

```
tabs.on('load', function(tab) {
    console.info( tab.url );
});
```

if I run firefox by jpm run, all work fine. But if I build the xpi and  install it to firefox then I'm getting tabs by other empty windows (if I call tabs.open opening new windows)

How fix it?

Now I'm trying the following [simple example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_(jpm)):

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Visit Mozilla",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
  tabs.open("http://www.mozilla.org/");
}
```

And this example works only if I run "jpm run".
if I build the extension and simple run the firefox (with the addon), the button do not created.

Comment: Are there exist other empty windows and you don't want to get them? Or there aren;t other windows?

Comment: see my post after edit

Comment: sorry, your question is very confusing.. are there two questions in your post: 1.) tabs.open opening in new windows. 2.) Action button not being visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer

If set setting history
"Never remember history" i got the problem

if set
"Remember history" problem has gone

it's very strange, i know

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking that your xpi can not locate the icons, so your plugin seems not working.
The icons should be in your `./data` directory and furthermore in your package.json it is a good practice to specify your `main`.  The file hierarchy of your working extension is:

```
├--data/
   ├-- icon-16.png
   ├-- icon-32.png
   ├-- icon-64.png
├--lib/
   ├-- main.js   
├--package.json
```

The `package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "stackexample",
  "title": "stackexample",
  "id": "mail@mail.com",
  "description": "An stackoverflow example",
  "author": "mail@mail.com",
  "main": "./lib/main.js",
  "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

Comment: This is probably the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In firefox after 'ready' event has been emitted, all properties relating to the tab's content can be used.You cannot access tab's properties on load event.

[Please refer to this link of addon sdk tabs ready event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#ready)